# Find the pmf of $W_1 = X_1 + X_2$ using convolution.

Tags: probability

> Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_8$ be a random sample from a distribution having pmf $$f(x)=\frac{x+1}{6},x=0,1,2$$ Find the pmf of $W_1 = X_1 + X_2$ using convolution.

I get the correct solutions for $0,1,2$ using the convolution formula I get but am off for $3$ and $4$:
$$\sum_{x=0}^{3}f(x)f(w-x) = \frac{1}{6}\frac{4}{6} + \frac{2}{6}\frac{3}{6} + \frac{3}{6}\frac{2}{6} + \frac{4}{6}\frac{1}{6} = \frac{20}{36} \neq \frac{12}{36}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot that $\mathbb{P}[X_i\geq 3]=0$:
$$\mathbb{P}[W_1=3]=\mathbb{P}[X_1=1]\mathbb{P}[X_2=2]+\mathbb{P}[X_1=2]\mathbb{P}[X_2=1]=\frac{2}{6}\cdot\frac{3}{6}+\frac{3}{6}\cdot\frac{2}{6}=\frac{12}{36},$$
$$\mathbb{P}[W_1=4]=\mathbb{P}[X_2=2]\mathbb{P}[X_1=2]=\frac{3}{6}\cdot\frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{4}.$$

Comment: Because there is no $3$ in the support, of course. Thanks!

Comment: I think I'm still unclear as to how to properly use the convolution formula when I seek $P(W_1 = 3)$.

Comment: @Chris: $$\mathbb{P}[X_1+X_2=k]=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{P}[X_1=m]\mathbb{P}[X_2=k-m],$$ but since the support of the pdf of $X_i$ is finite, only a finite number of terms survive.

Comment: I see, so terms out of bounds are simply dropped.